# Simple sql query return zero row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My query :

```
SELECT * FROM game_tbl WHERE ( `player_o` = 1 OR `player_x` = 1 ) AND ( `player_o` = NULL OR `player_x` = NULL )
```

**game_tbl :** 
[image]

use: mysql

and the result is zero rows, i want the 'game1'. Well i guess i can use other query but, important to my to understand right my wrong sql syntax, thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM game_tbl 
WHERE (`player_o` = 1 OR `player_x` = 1) AND (`player_o` IS NULL OR `player_x` IS NULL)
```

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) MySQL's documentation on working wiith `NULL` values.

> To test for NULL, use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators.
>
> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to
>   test for NULL.

Comment: So embarrassing you'r right tank you for you fix my syntax